# What is this extra "space" in Bootstrap <span> image?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am attempting to add an "X" icon to be able to click on and delete something in Backbone.js. I am using Bootstrap's `<span class="delete-acceptance glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn-sm"></span>` icon. Ideally, after adding CSS :hover, I can hover my mouse over the "X" and show the pointer. However, there seems to be extra space around the actual "X" icon, so that I can move my mouse in a small area around the "X", but the pointer still shows, so I'm guessing all of it is part of the  element.

Here's a picture of what I mean (it's the green area around the "X"):
[image: weird_spacing]

Why is that "extra" space there, and how can I go about getting rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a code example via jsfiddle or something similar, it's difficult to troubleshoot with just a screenshot.

Comment: Without in-depth knowledge it looks like its due to the background-color (green) showing around the background-image (X) because the image is smaller than the size of the element.

Answer (score 2):

That green area is the padding for the element, which is included as a part of it's [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).

Comment: I'm surprised why there would be a default padding around the icon. Thanks.

Comment: padding does seem like an odd choice for a span with no content (but still very possible of course) but maybe the content is added via css :before or somehow? Can you add any detail about that?

Comment: the green color is more or less the "standard" color for padding in developer tools. Margin is an yellow orangy color, and content is that baby blue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the green zone add `padding: 0;` to your element style. Otherwise for exclude the green zone from the clickable area add `box-sizing: content-box;`. You need to see the link in the post below for more details.